# Laravel ErrorException- missing argument 2

Tags: laravel

I am getting this error message, when I am trying to update. I would appreciate any help with this! This is my routes file:

```
Route::get('shelter/articles', ['as' => 'admin.shelter.articles', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@index']);
Route::get('shelter/article/create', ['as' => 'admin.shelter.article.create', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@create']);
Route::post('shelter/article/store', ['as' => 'admin.shelter.article.store', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@store']);
Route::get('shelter/article/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'admin.shelter.article.edit', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@edit']);
Route::put('shelter/article/update', ['as' => 'admin.shelter.article.update', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@update']);
```

This is my controller:

```
 public function update(EditRequest $request, $id){

$data=[];
$article = Article::findOrFail($id);
$slug = str_slug($request['name']);
if($slug!=$article->slug)
    $data=['slug' => $slug];
$article->fill(array_merge($this->fillobject($request), $data))
    ->update();
if($request->hasFile('upload_files'))
    $this->fileUpload($request->file('upload_files'), $article->id);

return Redirect::route('admin.shelter.article.edit',['id'=>$article->id]);}
```

And this is in my form:

```
{!! Form::model($article, ['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['admin.shelter.article.update', 'id' => $article->id],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Route::put('shelter/article/update/{id}', ['as' => 'admin.shelter.article.update', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@update']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specifiy the parameter in your update route:

```
Route::put('shelter/article/update', ['as' => 'admin.shelter.article.update', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@update'])
```

Just add the {id} route parameter to your update route as you did in the edit route

Answer (score 0):

First change the route to

```
Route::put('shelter/article/update/{id}', ['as' => 'admin.shelter.article.update', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@update']);
```

and then change form to

```
{!! Form::model($article, ['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['admin.shelter.article.update',$article->id],
```